# UsingFrontEnd with compute kernels

Tags: front-end, notebooks, parallelization

I am trying to have each compute kernel in a Mathematica session evaluate a notebook with `NotebookEvaluate`. Here is a sketch of my code:

```
LaunchKernels[]

computeNotebooks = Map[ FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],#}]&,
   {"ComputeNotebook1.nb","ComputeNotebook2.nb","ComputeNotebook3.nb"} ]

ParallelMap[ UsingFrontEnd[NotebookEvaluate[#,InsertResults->True]]&, computeNotebooks ]
```

The notebooks are located in the same directory as the driver notebook which contains the commands above.

With both Mathematica 10.4 and 11 the compute kernels seem to launch a front end but the `ParallelMap` command then never completes. Aborting the evaluation does not work either.

Also note that running the evaluation on the controller kernel works without problems:

```
Map[ UsingFrontEnd [NotebookEvaluate[#,InsertResults->True]]&, computeNotebooks ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Both `UsingFrontEnd` and `ParallelMap` are using the same mechanism for tracking the parent process, so they conflict with each other. This is a known issue. In the meantime, there is a workaround: a separate evaluator for each notebook. For instance, here is a set up I used recently,

```
(* Set up the known evaluators *)
$processorCount = 4;
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 EvaluatorNames -> Join[{"Local" -> {"AutoStartOnLaunch" -> True}}, 
  Table["Kernel" <> ToString[i] -> {"AutoStartOnLaunch" -> False}, 
   {i, $processorCount}]]]


MapIndexed[
 Function[{file, k},
  Module[{nb},
   nb = NotebookOpen[file];
   SetOptions[nb, 
     Evaluator -> "Kernel" <> ToString[Mod[First[k], $processorCount, 1]]
   ];
   FrontEndTokenExecute[nb, "SelectAll"];
   FrontEndTokenExecute[nb, "SelectionOpenAllGroups"];
   FrontEndTokenExecute[nb, "EvaluateCells"];
  ]
 ],
 files
];
```

The disadvantage of this method is that you cannot queue up the notebooks, if you have a lot of them, which would allow the load to be better balanced between the kernels.